# Check file size before creation

Tags: php, filesize

I'm creating a system to generate sitemaps for a application I'm working on, and one of the requirements for generating sitemaps is that each sitemap shouldn't have a file size greater than 10mb (10,485,760 bytes) as can be seen [here](http://www.sitemaps.org/faq.html).

This is my code to create the sitemap:

```
$fp = fopen($this->getSitemapPath() . $filename, 'w');
fwrite($fp, $siteMap->__toString());
fclose($fp);
```

The method `$siteMap->__toString()` holds a maximum of 50000 links.

Is there a way to check the resulting file size before calling the function `fwrite`?

Comment: Maybe that help you http://php.net/manual/en/function.fstat.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can use [`mb_strlen`](http://php.net/mb_strlen) to get the length of your string before you write it out to a file.

```
$contents = $siteMap->__toString();

if(mb_strlen($contents, '8bit') >= 10485760) {
    echo "Oops, this is too big";
} else {
    fwrite($fp, $contents);
}
```